# unable to load a javafx scene

Tags: java, javafx, resources, loading

I have a problem with loading a file. I'm trying to load the scene "areaView.fxml" with the following code:

```
public class View extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/areaView.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
}}
```

But when I launch I get an **InvocationTargetException**..

For information i'm on windows and the absolute path of the file is: **C:\Users\pierr\Desktop\Yves\resources\areaView.fxml**

It's probably a stupid mistake but I've been stuck on it for quite some time.... I'm almost sure it's related to the "/" but all my attempts to fix it have failed...

Thank you in advance

EDIT :

Here the full stack tace

[image]

EDIT n°2

Very strange thing when I test this:

```
 System.out.println(getClass().getResource("").toString());
```

I get this : **file:/C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/Yves/out/production/Yves/view/**

When I would have imagined getting this: **file:/C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/Yves/**

If i move my file to **file:/C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/Yves/out/production/Yves/view/** it works but in fact this solution is not satisfactory

Comment: The `InvocationTargetException` is probably not the actual error. Can you add the full StackTrace to your question?

Comment: Indeed you are right! It's an oversight on my part.

Comment: The actual error is "Location is not set." That means the `FXMLLoader` can not find the specified `fxml` file. You need to pass the loader a path relative to the class that's calling it. If your `Main.java` is in the root folder and "resources" branches off of that, try just `resources/areaView.fxml`.

Comment: Indeed, I think the same as you do. I've already tried your proposal but I get the same error. I edited my post (ed. 2). Do you think this is normal?

Comment: When you compile and run your application, the compiled files get placed in that **/out/** folder, so that is expected. That's where the app is actually running from.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe paths are case-sensitive Your path says "Resources" but you're passing "resources" to the FXMLLoader.

Comment: Okay, thank you! How can I load the files located in: C:/Users/pierr/Desktop/Yves/

For the r and the R's it's just a typo mistake when I wrote my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your resources folder should be under `projectName/src/main/resources`.

So in your case: `C:\Users\pierr\Desktop\Yves\src\main\resources\areaView.fxml`.

In such case `.getResource("areaView.fxml")` should be sufficient.

Just keep in mind that if you move your fxml to a different folder or you call `getResource` from a different folder than `src/main/java` you will have to change the relative path that you pass to the method.